# Android: after sliding a ListView up with animation, it doesn't re-size to fill the screen

Tags: android, animation

in my current view I have a ListView that takes up all the screen. When the user pushes a menu button, I want the list view to slide down, revealing a view thats hidden under it in the Relative layout. This is the code I'm using.

```
     ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvDashboard);
     Animation anim2 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, ListHeight);
     anim1.setDuration(500);
     anim2.setFillAfter(true);
     lv.startAnimation(anim2);
```

it works fine on the way down, but when I want tap the button to slide it back up, the List view is truncated ( because it was previously slid down and was taking up a smaller portion of the screen) and when it reaches its final position, it remains that smaller size and it leaves a big white space on my screen. once I touch anywhere on the screen, the list re-sizes and goes back to normal height.
What I need to happen is that the ListView re-sizes BEFORE it moves, so as it slides up no part of the screen is left naked. OR for the ListView to not re-size at all but to simply just slide off the screen.

UPDATE: I was able to get desired effect using PropertyAnimation (instead of ViewAnimation), but I'm still curious if there is a way to fix this glitch.